# how to change group header values each time in datareport in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

i am developing application in vb6.0 here i am using datareport for displaying report i want to assign values for each group header RptLabel at run time without using dataenvironment please advise me to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [hierarchical recordset](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196029) for the datareport to use as a datasource.

First off, you need to set the recordset's ActiveConnection property to MsDataShape :

```
rsDataSource.ActiveConnection = "Provider=MsDataShape;Data Provider=None;"
```

Here is an example of how you can define the structure of the recordset :

```
    rsDatasouce.Source = "SHAPE APPEND NEW adInteger As ParentId, " & _
    "New adVarChar(100) As HeaderValue1, " & _
    "New adVarChar(100) As HeaderValue2, " & _
    "((SHAPE APPEND New adInteger As ParentGroupId, " & _
                   "New adInteger As ChildGroupId, " & _
                   "New adVarChar(25) As ChildValue1, " & _ 
                   "New adVarChar(25) As ChildValue2, " & _
                   "((SHAPE APPEND New adInteger As ChildId, " & _
                                  "New adVarChar(8) As SubChildValue1, " & _
                                  "New adVarChar(100) As Description " & _
                     "RELATE ChildGroupId To ChildId) AS ChildDetail) " & _
       "RELATE ParentId To ParentGroupId) AS GroupDetail"
```

Having done this you need to populate the hierarchical recordset.